# How to npm install node-fibers on intranet?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-fibers

It looks like fibers is trying to talk to `104.20.23.46:443` but since I don't have an internet connection it fails. Is there any way to get around this?

```
npm install node-fibers-1.0.5.tar.gz

> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/wekan/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

(node:35623) DeprecationWarning: child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.23.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/wekan/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-fibers-1.0.5.tar.gz"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fibers
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/wekan/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried extracting the gzipped tarball and "npm install" from within the extraction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on one of the platforms that fibers provides pre built binaries for then it shouldn't trigger the full build and need to download anything:

```
→ find . -name fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-ia32-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-ia32-48/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-48/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-ia32-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-ia32-48/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-48/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/win32-ia32-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/win32-ia32-48/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/win32-x64-46/fibers.node
./node_modules/fibers/bin/win32-x64-48/fibers.node
```

The 46 and 48 refer an internal module version number that Node keeps, which normally stays the same for a major release number (ie 4/6):

```
→ node -pe 'process.version'
v6.9.5
→ node -pe 'process.versions.modules'
48
```

and

```
→ node -pe 'process.version'
v4.7.0
→ node -pe 'process.versions.modules'
46
```

If you don't have a machine that fits you probably need to compile on an equivalent machine with internet access, then move the `node_modules/fibers` directory over.